# Make a composite stream in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have several streams that I would like to connect with pipes

`new compositeStream([A,B,C])`

I'd like to return a single stream `S` in which `D.pipe S.pipe E` will pipe the output of D through A, B and C, then out through E.

Is there a simple way to do this?

`A.pipe B.pipe C` does not work, because it returns only the destination stream. I want a new stream with an entrance at A

Answer (score 0):

As a tentative solution, `.pipeline` from `pipe-iterators` will do this.

`compositePipe = pi.pipeline([A,B,C])`

It would be great if there was a more native solution.

I'd like to be able to chain pipes like

```
compositePipe = 
A.pipeline(
B.pipeline(
C)));
```